# My Xamarin Forms Android has just one Supported ABI in the Advanced options. Should all of them be selected?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the way my app is currently set up:

[image]

Could someone tell me, should I be selecting all of these and if not then will that mean I can only support a limited number of devices?  I notice when I create an .apk it still gives 5-6 different files but I just upload the one that I think contains all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, we will select all of them. Because we do not know what kind of CPU architecture mobile phone the user is using.

> I notice when I create an .apk it still gives 5-6 different files but I just upload the one that I think contains all of them

If you want to generate just one .apk(need support `armeabi-v7a`, `x86`,`arm64-v8a` and `x86_64`), you can unselect the `Generate one package(.apk) per selected ABI`, regenerate the .apk file.

[image]

If you want to select the `Generate one package(.apk) per selected ABI`, you will get 5 .apk files like following format.

```
com.xx.xx-arm64-v8a.apk
com.xx.xx-armeabi-v7.apk
com.xx.xx-x86_64.apk
com.xx.xx-x86.apk
com.xx.xx.apk
```

select the `com.xx.xx.apk` , it support `arm64-v8a` , `rmeabi-v7`, `x86_64` and `x86` CPU architectures at the same time.